# Need to get an attribute for runtime

Tags: android

I've been researching this for days. There is a piece of code I am working on that depends on knowing whether clipToPadding is set to true or false. While the documentation provides a solution for setting this attribute, I cannot find an effective way to read the attribute that does not depend on XML. Ordinarily, this would not be a problem but the class I created is meant to be subclasses by layout objects and may or may not be generated by XML. Is there a way to get the value of clipToPadding without having to rely on XML attributes?

Thanks in advance,
Fuzzical Logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Android's source code, the information you look for is in a private field called mGroupFlags. There is no read accessor for this field, so I guess using the xml attribute is your only way of doing this... or you could rewrite your ViewGroup (and children class) adding the missing accessor to get the clipToPadding attribute.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. It seems silly (in this case, but only because I need it now) that there is a write but no read accessor. I suppose that must be due to some potential violation or taint to the UI thread. I will try an alternative solution.